# Verify Stokes' theorem for $F=2yzi-(x+3y-2)j+(x^2+z)k$ where $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: calculus, analysis, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

Verify Stokes' theorem for $F=2yzi-(x+3y-2)j+(x^2+z)k$ where $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the surface of intersection of the cylinders $x^2 + z^2 = a^2$ and $x^2 + y^2 =a^2$ in the first octant.

I have evaluated the line integral $\int_C F.dr=-\frac{a^2}{12}(3\pi+8a)$ where C is the boundary of the surface S with four segments as shown in the fig with arrows.

I want to find the surface integral $\int\int_S curl\,F\cdot n\, dS$

$curl F=-2(x-y)j-(1-2z)k$, $n=\frac{yj+zk}{a}$, $dS=\frac{a}{z}dxdy$,

I am unable to solve $\int\int_S curl\,F\cdot n\, dS$. Please help me to solve it.

[image]

Comment: What is keeping from computing the surface integral? You clearly need to split the surface in two... Are you able to parametrize these two surfaces?

Comment: @PierreCarre How to parametrize and which two surface integrals? I thought to take a projection of the whole surface on the $xy$ plane, where the projection surface is a quarter circle. Please help me in full

Comment: Note that surface AEB is everywhere perpendicular to $\hat{k}$ and surface BED is everywhere perpendicular to $\hat{j}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that at the intersection of both surfaces, $x^2 + y^2 = x^2 + z^2 \implies y = z$

Surface $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$ should be parametrized as,

$ \phi(z, t) = (a \cos t, a \sin t, z)$ with normal vector $ \vec n_1 = (a \cos t, a \sin t, 0)$

There is also a small mistake in your curl. It should be, $\nabla \times \vec F = \langle 0, 2 (y - x), - (1 + 2z) \rangle$

The surface integral is,

$ \displaystyle  \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{a \sin t} 2a^2 \sin t ~(\sin t - \cos t) ~ dz ~ dt $

Similarly surface $x^2 + z^2 = a^2$ can be parametrized as $(a \sin t, y, a \cos t)$ with normal vector $ \vec n_2 = (a \sin t, 0, a \cos t)$

The surface integral is,

$ \displaystyle  \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{a \cos t} - a \cos t ~(1 + 2 a \cos t) ~ dy ~ dt $

Adding both, we do get $ ~~\displaystyle -\frac{a^2}{12}(3\pi+8a)$.

Comment: Thanks... What is the need of "at the intersection of both surfaces $x^2 + y^2 = x^2 + z^2 \implies y = z$"...I mean, where you have used it for the surface integrals ? Or, you are just mentioning for the drawing of the fig?

Comment: Also, I would like to know that where the surface integrals can be solved by taking projections, for ex, taking projection of surface AEB is and surface BED on xz and xy plane respectively? If not, why such type of projections are not working...

Comment: We parametrize a circle (its perimeter) as $(a \cos t, a \sin t)$ where $a$ is the radius of the circle. For a cylinder, you just need to add the second dimension which is its height. That is why we are parametrizing cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$ as $(a \cos t, a \sin t, z)$. The lower bound of $z$ is $0$ and the upper bound is the intersection of both surfaces, which is $z = y  = a \sin t$.

Comment: Yes you can use the projection in xz or yz plane for cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$ but given a cylinder, the parametrization that I have used is easier and straightforward.

Comment: Only the last quarry: $$curf\,F.n_1=2a(sin t-cos t)sin t$$ and $dS=dxdz/|n_1.j|=-adz\,dt$ as $dx=-a\,sin t\,dt$, so a negative sign remains, i.e I got the first surface integral as $\displaystyle  \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{a \sin t}- 2a^2 \sin t ~(\sin t - \cos t) ~ dz ~ dt$

Comment: Is $t$ is from $\pi/2$ to 0?

Comment: Please suggest about the orientation of surfaces... Is my $dS$ ok?

Comment: Sorry I was away from the site. If you are taking the projection in xz-plane, the limits of integration for $x$ will be $0$ to $a$. If you are substituting $x = a \cos t$, limits of $t$ will be $\pi/2$ to $0$